# Coldfusion - Remove all non-numeric values from a list?

Tags: list, coldfusion

I have a list of IDs being passed through the URL. I want to do some sanitizing before running a query based on those IDs. I have this:

```
<cfset URL.ID = ReReplaceNoCase(URL.ID,"[^0-9]","","ALL")>
```

But I realize that's stripping the comma out also. Is there a simple way to remove non numeric values from a list in Coldfusion?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not just add a comma to your regex?

```
<cfset URL.ID = ReReplaceNoCase(URL.ID,"[^0-9]","","ALL")>
```

becomes

```
<cfset URL.ID = ReReplaceNoCase(URL.ID,"[^0-9,]","","ALL")>
```

Comment: Curious, once you have the cleaned up URL.ID (including extra commas), could you throw it into a structure, then into an array and then arraytolist to clean up the commas?  This would take 3-4 lines of code (including the regex expression).?

Answer (score 4):

```
<cfscript>
//Test Case
URL.ID= "abc,12,3,zoiui fdsoaiu ,323333";

//URL.ID= "12,3,323333"
URL.ID= reReplace( URL.ID , "([^0-9,]+,)" , "" , "all" );

</cfscript>
```

That being said, you'd want to put this in a `<cfqueryparam .. list= "true" />`

Comment: +1 This regex work's better than @Sean Coyne's. It works correctly with my example.

Comment: Looking at this again. There's a problem.. it assumes there's a trailing comma.

do reReplace( URL.ID & "," .. ) and it'll take care of that

Answer (score 3):

Regex still leaves extra commas in the string and accepts partial numbers, instead I'd use a loop with integer validation:

```
<cfset url.id = "100,abc,102z,eee,22.5,773">
<!--- 100,,102,,225,773 --->
<cfoutput>#ReReplaceNoCase(URL.ID,"[^0-9,]","","ALL")#<br /></cfoutput>

<cfset dirtyIds = listToArray(url.id)>
<cfset cleanIds = []>
<cfloop array="#dirtyIds#" index="dirtyId">
    <cfif isValid("integer",dirtyId)><cfset arrayAppend(cleanIds, dirtyId)></cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfset url.id = arrayToList(cleanIds)>
<!--- 100, 773 --->
<cfoutput>#url.id#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

@orangepips

isNumeric() should work as well.

```
<cfset url.id = "100,abc,102z,eee,22.5,773">
<cfset variables.newlist = ''>
<cfloop list="#url.id#" index="i">
    <cfif isNumeric(i)>
        <cfset variables.newlist = ListAppend(variables.newlist,i)>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#variables.newlist#</cfoutput>
```